# JQuery not working. (Function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So when I put

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

at the top of this

```
$(function() {  
    jQuery.scrollSpeed(1920, 800); 
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#open-io").click(function (){
        //console.log("asdfasdf");
        $("#navi").addClass("expand");
    });

    $("#close-io").click(function (){
        //console.log("asdfasdf");
        $("#navi").removeClass("expand");
    });
});
```

Is not working all.

But if I put the top one to the bottom one look like this

```
$(function() {  
    jQuery.scrollSpeed(1920, 800); 
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#open-io").click(function (){
        //console.log("asdfasdf");
        $("#navi").addClass("expand");
    });

    $("#close-io").click(function (){
        //console.log("asdfasdf");
        $("#navi").removeClass("expand");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

The smooth scroll is working but the fancybox is not working. Help me on this.
I'm newbie might hard to understand.

This is inside my body/body

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.37797.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
<script src="js/parallax.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    jQuery.scrollSpeed(1920, 800);
  });

  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#open-io").click(function() {
    //console.log("asdfasdf");
    $("#navi").addClass("expand");
  });

  $("#close-io").click(function() {
    //console.log("asdfasdf");
    $("#navi").removeClass("expand");
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

This is the link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

This is what Console show,

```
Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:6 GET file:///C:/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:217 GET file:///C:/js/modernizr.custom.37797.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:218 GET file:///C:/js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:219 GET file:///C:/js/parallax.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:221 GET file:///C:/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:222 GET file:///C:/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:227 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.scrollSpeed is not a function(anonymous function) @ Horizontal_MouseWheel_Parallax.html:227j @ jquery-latest.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-latest.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery-latest.min.js:2J @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Is the `fancybox.js` script included in your page? Also note that you don't need multiple `document.ready` handlers - your code can all be placed in a single one.

Comment: Idk how to check the console for errors. Yes fancybox.js is include my page.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

Comment: If you are developing using chrome or firefox, IIRC you can press `F12` to see the console.  BTW, your URL for fancybox looks incomplete.  Do you really have a directory called `fancybox/source/...` next to your HTML file?

Comment: Hang on I'll put this

Comment: Why don't you have everything you want to be run when `$(document).ready()` inside `$(document).ready(function() { /** HERE! **/ });` ???

Comment: Maybe you could show us any of your **html** code where your `fancybox` is?

Comment: I just edited is it okay for this?

Comment: Nobody else noticed that you've included jQuery twice.   jQuery needs to be included *before* your plugins and do not include it a second time.

Comment: @Sparky nobody noticed because that **html** code was not there until we told him to attach it into his post and he edited. Now there it is! ;-)

Comment: Regardless, it's a mess.

Comment: @Sparky you're right!

Comment: Sorry guys. Just start to learn  how to place properly. Hang on im trying

Comment: I guess im still can't get it. What mean {jQuery twice} and {jQuery needs to be included before your plugins and do not include it a second time.}

Comment: @CheeYong of course, mate! None of us were born knowing anything! :-)

Comment: You only need once call yo jQuery and loaded before of any other plugin that depends on it (order matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a few things but I would do the following to troubleshoot the issue:

**1)** Rearrange your JavaScript imports as follows. Also, add a leading slash (`/`) to the source paths otherwise the imports won't work on nested pages (you should use **absolute** paths, your paths are currently **relative**).

(I've also removed a duplicate jQuery import)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<script src="/js/modernizr.custom.37797.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
<script src="/js/parallax.js"></script>

<script src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

**2)** Merge the JavaScript into one `$(document).ready` function:

(I've also updated your `.click` handlers into the recommended `.on` handler instead)

```
// This could also start with the following line
// $(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {   

  jQuery.scrollSpeed(1920, 800);
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();

  $("#open-io").on('click', function (){
    //console.log("asdfasdf");
    $("#navi").addClass("expand");
  });

  $("#close-io").on('click', function (){
    //console.log("asdfasdf");
    $("#navi").removeClass("expand");
  });

});
```

Try this and see if helps.

Let me know what you find.

Comment: @CheeYoung that's exactly what we were talking about!

Comment: Helo, thanks for the reply. But this is not working.

Comment: @CheeYong - No problem, what doesn't work? Are you creating this online or on your local computer...is there a link you can share that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @CheeYong - Did you add the leading slashes to your imports?

Comment: Yes im working on local computer since this is my 1st assignment for the web course. Yes i added the / to my link.

Comment: I can send you the file privately if you want haha

Comment: I don't mind seeing the files but it doesnt guarantee I'll be able to duplicate the issue. Can you view the console on your browser and see if there are any errors? (Press 'F12' on your keyboard and along the top you'll see 'Elements', 'Network', 'Sources' ... 'Console'. Click on the 'Console' tab and reload your webpage)

Comment: @CheeYong - If you check your console as instructed above and let me know what errors are stated, it should help to narrow down your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I just done it properly.

So I rearrange the JQuery and I also remove 1 of the

```
jquery.min.js
```

So overall look like this

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.37797.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
<script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

For the  `$(document).ready(function() {` I also use the one that you helpe me arrange properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

jQuery.scrollSpeed(1920, 800);
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

$("#open-io").on('click', function (){
 //console.log("asdfasdf");
 $("#navi").addClass("expand");
});

$("#close-io").on('click', function (){
 //console.log("asdfasdf");
 $("#navi").removeClass("expand");
});

});
```

And also I did not add the slash to my path. If I add it, it will not working.

Working

```
fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
```

Not Working

```
/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
```